# How to remove file size and/or file name on dropzone thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Like the title says I want to find out a way to remove the file size text and the file name text on the dropzone thumbnail when my mouse goes on the thumbnail. Is there a setting something that makes this easier or do I have to write jquery scripts.

[image].

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue few days ago, this will solve your problem go to dropzone.js find

`previewTemplate:`
there you have divs with class dz-size and dz-filename just add
`hidden`
and they won't show when you upload image successfully you can do the same for the failed upload (remove the x circle in the middle `dz-error-mark` or you can even customize it.
Hope this helps!

Bellow are the images of how I modified it.
[image: Upload Dialog Using Dropzone]
[image: Image Loaded]

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the css, I believe that effect gets triggered by the hover so you can put it to not to display it. There is a class called dz-details.